# Product of corresponding elements in 2 arrays

Tags: python, algorithm, array

> Given two arrays `A` and `B`, of length `N` and length `k` respectively, if we move `B` over `A` and take the sum of product of corresponding elements of `A` and `B`, then find the minimum of those sum of products.

For example, if `A=[2,3,4,5]` and `B=[1,3]`, then after moving `B` over `A`, we get 3 possible values `[2*1+3*3, 3*1+4*3, 4*1+3*5]`, max of which is 19.

I tried coding for this and reached an \$O(n^2)\$ solution. Can I reduce the algorithm's complexity here?

My code in Python:

```
A=[2,3,4,5]
B=[1,3]
print max([sum([A[i+j]*B[j] for j in xrange(len(B))]) for i in xrange(len(A)-len(B)+1)])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is effectively a convolution problem. Theoretically, this can (potentially) be done faster by a conversion to the frequency domain, that is, using a [fast Fourier transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform) (FFT) convolution.

Writing a high-performance FFT convolution isn't something I'd want to reproduce here (even if I could reproduce it, which to be perfectly honest, I couldn't). Thankfully, I don't have to: libraries like [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org/) and [`scipy`](http://www.scipy.org/) provide this functionality: see [`scipy.signal.fftconvolve`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.fftconvolve.html).

The only thing that we have to be careful with is that convolution reverses the second array, so we must provide that in a reversed form:

```
import numpy
from scipy.signal import fftconvolve

x = numpy.array([2,3,4,5])
y = numpy.array([1,3])
maximum = numpy.max(fftconvolve(x, y[::-1], mode='valid')) # reversed view of y
```

For small arrays, this is likely to be slower than the naïve O(*n*<sup>2</sup>) convolution, due to the overhead of conversions (and multiplying complex numbers). If you are in this case, then you should try [`scipy.signal.convolve`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve.html).

For an in-depth writeup of computational complexity comparisons between the naïve convolution and the fast Fourier transform, see [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/171757/computational-complexity-of-correlation-in-time-vs-multiplication-in-frequency-s).